# The X-Files: bizarre stuff at opening credits

Tags: the-x-files, title-sequence

Does anyone know what kind of double stuff is that (at the left and the right sides)?

[image: bizarre stuff]

Comment: Those are sprouting seedlings.

Comment: fetus/baby walrus ? :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It's a seed germinating

....although highly sped up.

[image]